# Is it possible to load a webpage inside fckeditor?

Tags: fckeditor

Is it possible to load a webpage in a fckeditor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no we can not open a webpage in fck editor we can do only

- Cut, Paste and Past as Plain Text,
- Undo and Redo Paste from Word cleanup
- with auto detection Image insertion,

  with upload and server browsing
- support Table creation and editing
  (add, delete rows, etc)